# MDM - Test managed configuration deployment for mobile (Android/iOS) apps

Tags: android, ios, mdm, android-restrictions

In the past we were able to deploy private versions of our app to EMM's (e.g. VMWare, MobileIron) and test out managed configurations. But today, we are unable to test new app updates within a managed environment.

**Android** https://developer.android.com/work/managed-configurations

With new Google updates EMMs are no longer able to upload private versions of our app if the app package id conflicts with a publicly available app on Google Play. For regulatory reasons we are unable to just change the package id and test because it is technically not testing the same binaries. Best we can do now is simulate a managed environment using Test DCP : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.afwsamples.testdpc

Is this the best we can test without publicly releasing the app update to Google Play? We have contacted VMWare and basically got the same answer but would like a confirmation. Uploading the app to a closed testing track on Google Play and then trying to importing to EMM did not work either.

**iOS** https://www.appconfig.org/ios/

Basically the same issue for iOS. Apple has kind of removed the Enterprise Developer Account which we previously used to sign and upload our own versions to EMM. The new eligibility requirements are too much. Alternatively, none of the EMMs work with TestFlight. And for iOS we do not know of any app like Android Test DCP to simulate a managed environment. I read a few github chains and Apple forums where companies are just releasing the app publicly then testing to make sure everything works. That can't be right, right?

Comment: For iOS, have you tried using an ad-hoc build? This should work much the same as an enterprise build except that you will need the test device udid(s) in the provisioning profile.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting, the adhoc build is still accepted by VMWare. Will have to test if pushing managed configuration settings still works. I think we didn't look at this earlier because it is still the same regulatory issue. That is for formal testing the final IPA needs to be used, not an adhoc one. Not my rules.

Comment: There is no difference between an ad-hoc build and a release build aside from the signing, however if an ad-hoc build isn't acceptable then an enterprise build wouldn't be either as the signing is again different to an App Store release.  If the only build that is acceptable from a regulatory point of view is an App Store release then you need to release it to the store and test that.